# Sticky posts exeed posts per page limit

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, offset

as I need some specification in my theme, I would like to show 16 posts on my pages. The 16 posts should also included the sticky posts: So I have 1 sticky post at the moment, so it show show 1 sticky and 15 normal posts on the first page.

I fixed this by my code already, but now I have the problem that 1 post disappears in the whole blog section. I guess it is because WP thinks, that it should continue with the nr 16 of posts.

I heard about `offsets` but I don´t really know how to apply this to my code.

So that what I have got so far in my `functions.php`:

```
/*limit posts */


add_action('pre_get_posts', 'ad_custom_query');

function ad_custom_query($query) {


if ($query->is_main_query() && is_home()) {


// set the number of posts per page

$posts_per_page = 16;

// get sticky posts array

$sticky_posts = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );


// if we have any sticky posts and we are at the first page

if (is_array($sticky_posts) && !$query->is_paged()) {


// counnt the number of sticky posts

$sticky_count = count($sticky_posts);


// and if the number of sticky posts is less than

// the number we want to set:

if ($sticky_count < $posts_per_page) {

$query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page - $sticky_count);


// if the number of sticky posts is greater than or equal

// the number of pages we want to set:

} else {

$query->set('posts_per_page', 1);

}


// fallback in case we have no sticky posts

// and we are not on the first page

} else {

$query->set('posts_per_page', $posts_per_page);

}

}

}
```